# Process netbeans.exe (NetBeans 7.0) consuming high amount of CPU usage

Tags: java, netbeans, cpu-usage, high-load, netbeans-7

I had Netbeans 6.8 installed on my PC a day back...
I uninstalled Netbeans 6.8 completely and then installed NetBeans IDE 7.0 (Build 201104080000)...

Now the process netbeans.exe consumes high amount of CPU usage varying from 30% to 95%...
This happens **only when a Java project is opened** (only opened not build/run)...

Initially when i open netbeans 7.0 the CPU usage remains normal (3% to 7%)...
If i open a Java project or start a new Java project (Java application, Java Web , Java EE or Java ME)... the CPU usage goes mad consuming randomly from 30% to 95% (due to the process netbeans.exe)....
If i **close the Java project the CPU usage still remains high** and continues to do so until i exit Netbeans 7.0...

It doesn't happen if i open a different project like PHP web application...

Why is this happening?
Should i revert back to netbeans 6.8 or maybe install netbeans 6.9??

Comment: any opinions / suggestions will be helpful..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Forget it.... I uninstalled Netbeans 7 and installed Netbeans 6.9.1...
No problems now...

Damn I hate beta versions..  :0